# Getting back [object HTMLInputElement] as a result

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom

JS code

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
});

function change() {
    document.getElementById('the-name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('name');
}
```

HTML code

```
<p> What's your name? <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id = "name"></input></p>

<button id="button" onclick= "change(document.getElementById('name'))"> Answer </button>

<p>Hello <span id = "the-name"></span>,</p>
```

With the code above, I get the result in the title whenever I try to run it by clicking the button. Could someone point me to the right direction by telling me what I am doing wrong? Much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are assigning a `HTMLInputElement` to the `innerHTML` of your element instead of a `text` or a `HTML content` in the line:

```
document.getElementById('the-name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('name');
```

You need to get the input value:

```
document.getElementById('the-name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value;
```

**Demo:**

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {});

function change() {
  document.getElementById('the-name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> What's your name? <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name"></input>
</p>

<button id="button" onclick="change(document.getElementById('name'))"> Answer </button>

<p>Hello <span id="the-name"></span>,</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the whole HTML-Input Element to your `<span>`.

You have to use the value property of you HTML-Input Element to get its value.

```
document.getElementById('the-name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value
```